# jquery returning object instead of id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have

```
<li class="live_item" data-id="1">
                        <span class="number">1</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <label>Test</label>
                  </li>
```

And this

```
$(".live_item").on("click",function(){

    alert($($(this).data("id")));
});
```

Can you tell my why it is retuning an object and not the number 1? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the outer `$` call.

Comment: because you wrap it in a $() ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the returned value of `$(this).data('id')` to the `$` jQuery function. That will convert the value to a jQuery object. That's why the alert displays `[object Object]` instead of the data `id` value.

```js
$(".live_item").on("click",function() {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="live_item" data-id="1">
    <span class="number">1</span>
    <i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label>Test</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra `$` symbol in the `alert()` method...

```js
$(".live_item").on("click",function() {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="live_item" data-id="1">
    <span class="number">1</span>
    <i class="fa fa-television" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label>Test</label>
</li>
```

Comment: i had 2 hours messing with this. I'm without hairs now. Thanks so much didnt see that

Comment: An explaination it's appreciated. Teach them how to fish instead of just offer them fish as food :)